SAGA in QGIS 3.30 and versions above
I created a plugin that needs to create a drainage area from an outlet point, for this, I was using the SAGA "upslope area" tool, but I realized just now that I was using SAGA Next Gen in the plugin, which it would require the user to install SAGA Next Gen and only then use my plugin. I would like to know if there is a way to resolve this situation.
I was thinking about two situations:

finding another way to generate an upslope area from an outlet point.
being able to import SAGA tools directly into the plugin code, this way, it would not force the user to previously download SAGA Next Gen.

What do you think?
